# gradle module resolution based on build types

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I'm fairly new to android development and gradle configuration in general but all the same have been tasked with this challenge. I need to disable a specific plugin/module (sorry not sure what even to call it) based on build types.

A bit more information is that the dependecies I want to disable are firebase dependencies. Not sure if this matters but I'm adding this to the question as well.

We have types as follows:

```
        debug {
           ...code here
        }
        qa {
           ...code here
        }
        release {
          ...code here
        }
        stage {
          ...code here
        }
        sft {
          ...code here
        }
        sandbox {
          ...code here
        }
```

And then we have dependencies as follows:

```
dependencies {
    ... dependencies that need to be there


    // these are the main concerns
    Implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4"
    Implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.0.4"
}
```

My questions here are

1. Can I shut down the dependencies in question here?
2. If I can how can I do so conditionally for only specific build types?

Alternately:
If either cannot be done here, how is this done?

OR

is it possible to disable firebase messaging via the

```
resValue("bool", "FIREBASE_MESSAGE_ENABLED", "false")
```

I'm not sure where to look for what values are allowed for resValue in a built types.

thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

`debugImplementation "com.url.thing-support:version.subversion"`
for debug buildType

`qaImplementation "com.url.thing-support:version.subversion.1"`
for qa buildType
and so on...

Comment: Hi clzd0792. I've tried that. And I'm still getting build errors related to the packages under com.url.thing-support:version.subversion